# Differential of the greatest integer function

Tags: calculus

So I know that the derivative of the greatest integer function is zero.

That is if $f(x) = [x]$ then $df/dx = 0$. Then, a friend asked me for the *differential* , $df$ of $f(x)$. My answer was zero. He doesn't agree, so I am here to resolve my doubts.

**Please what is the differential of the greatest integer function?**

Comment: For some purposes, you might want to say the differential is $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-n)$, with $\delta$ being the dirac delta distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function is constant on non-integer, its derivative is $0$ on non-integer values.  Since the function is not continuous on integer values, its derivative undefined at the integers.

Comment: But right hand and left derivative are both equal to zero and derivative is defined for integers.